# How do we solve the following equation using Green's function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function, partial-differential-equations

$$y'' +k^2 y=e^{-\alpha|x|} $$

And I know that the Green's Function is:
$$G(x,x') = -\frac{i}{2k} e^{ik|x-x'|}   $$

How do I go about finding the solution?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Do you mean ODE?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more general, but also more insightful.

For every nontrivial polynomial of deg. $n$, one can find a distribution $\phi \in \mathscr{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that (see the book of H${\ddot{\text{o}}}$rmander)

$$
p(D)\phi = \delta
$$

Then, for every $f \in \mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ it follows that the solution $u$ can be written as $u = \phi * f$, and we see that indeed

$$
p(D)u = p(D)(\phi * f) = \big(p(D)\phi\big)*f = \delta * f = f 
$$

---

In your case, $p(D) \equiv \partial_x^2 + k^2$, $\phi \equiv G$ and $f \equiv e^{-\alpha|x|}$. The solution is then
$$
u(x) = G(x,s) * f(s) = \int G(x,s)f(s)\ \mathrm{d}s
$$

Comment: I tried integrating G(x,x')*f(x') dx' with the limits -inf to inf. However, the function tends to blow up... It would be helpful if you can show how to find the solution

Comment: Yes, integration is in $(-\infty,\infty)$ but $f$ has compact support for $\alpha > 0$. What exactly is blowing up?

Comment: I'm not understanding how would you go about the integration.. Can you please show how do I do it?

Comment: @Manas You have a closed form of the solution in terms of the integral that I just wrote. You replace $G$ and $f$ with your functions and that's it. You can compute the integral if you want, what's wrong with it? What is it that you don't understand? What is blowing up? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Manas Remember that $e^{ix} = \cos x + i \sin x$